# Download button not working for the first time

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, download

I'm working on XHTML page that download file from FTP server using download component of PrimeFaces and command button.

When running the application on Tomcat server, then open the page and press download for the first time it goes to the download function and download file successfully into `DefaultStreamedContent` object but nothing appears to be downloaded on the browser and the page seems to be refreshed after waiting for tomcat message that appears below in my page (this all for the first hit only).

But when pressing download for the second time it goes to download function for the second time and download file successfully, but what appears on the browser is the first downloaded file.

Also, when I removed the file and started the app again: the first hit of download know that file not exits.

This is another case for summary:

- 1-first hit on download file X, nothing appears on browser to be downloaded
- 2-second hit on download file Y, it downloads file x that's why i know it downloaded the first file

Note:

1. No exceptions happened and first hit downloaded file successfully in debug mode but nothing appears on browser for the first time only
2. I tried to put this button in another blank page and new form but same problem happened.

My XHTML page code:

```
<p:commandButton id="downloadButton"
    value="#{messages.label_download}" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"
    onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);"
    action="#{rapportiprovaBean.handleFileDownload(rapportiprova)}"
    immediate="true" style="width= 5%">
    <p:fileDownload
        value="#{rapportiprovaBean.fileManager.downloadedFile}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

My managed bean code:

```
public void handleFileDownload(Rapportiprova rapporti) {
    Documenti documenti = new Documenti();
    documentiService = new DocumentiServiceImpl();
    fileManager = new FileManager();
    try {
        selectedRapportiProva = rapporti;
        if (selectedRapportiProva.getIdDoc() != null) {
            DDT_Server_Info = fileManager.loadDDT_Info();
            documenti = selectedRapportiProva.getIdDoc();
            folder = documenti.getIdRif().getDescrizione();
            fileName = documenti.getDoc();
            InputStream stream = fileManager.downloadDDTFile(fileName, DDT_Server_Info, folder);

            if (stream != null)
            {
                DefaultStreamedContent streamContent=new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, FileManager.getFileContentType(fileName), fileName);
                fileManager.setDownloadedFile(streamContent);
            }
            stream.close();

        } else {
            fileManager.setDownloadedFile(null);
            FacesMessage facesMessage = MessageFactory.getMessage("message_error_file_not_exits",
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesMessage facesMessage = MessageFactory.getMessage("message_error_download_file",
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
    }
    fileManager.setDownloadedFile(null);
}
```

My question is, why file is downloaded internally and not appears on browser to be downloaded for the first hit, but in second hit of this button or any other button for other file, it shows the first file downloaded on the browser which is wrong behavior?

Comment: If you add `System.out.println` to methods `rapportiprovaBean.fileManager.downloadedFile`, `rapportiprovaBean.handleFileDownload` do they invoke in correct order? Also did you try without `immediate` attribute?

Comment: First Hit :"1-in start of download inside rapporti bean
2-set downloaded file method-File manager
3-in end of download inside rapporti bean


Second Hit: 
1-get download file method-File manager
2-in start of download inside rapporti bean
3-set downloaded file method-File manager
4-in end of download inside rapporti bean

in second hit it calls getter method before entering the function which already have the first file cached from the first hit but what do you think shall i do to make it download the file from the first hit?